# How to delete a folder if there is a file move is success by script

Tags: python, shell

I wrote a shell script to move `*.html` files from 100 folders.

> ```
> cd 1498224124_1_OCR ; python obatchocr.py ; mv *.html /var/www/html/ocr/ocr-by-batch-number/  ; cd ../
> cd 1498224124_2_OCR ; python obatchocr.py ; mv *.html /var/www/html/ocr/ocr-by-batch-number/  ; cd ../
> ```

Actually, few folders does not have `*.html` file. I want to find the folders which does not have `*.html` file. So, i want to delete the folder if there is `*.html` move is success by shell script.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is test if the end of the file ends with ".html"

To do this, here is the written code. You should easily be able to translate this into what you are doing.

```
for every file in folder
if name.end == ".html":
move file
else
delete file
```

This is not the exact code you will need to use, but hopefully this has helped :)